# Background image not showing in <div> container

Tags: html, css, image, sprite

I have a silly little problem.  It seems that the CSS background image attribute will just not work.

- The image is in DIV container in the back which i thought may be interfering with it but after removing it, it still didn't work (currently removed)
- I've tried placing the css code in different classes and it still doesn't work
- I've made sure the image is the same directory of html & css files.

HTML

```
<div class="detail_below">

<div class="course-downloadPF">
<a class="thickbox" href="http://www.google.com">Project Files Included</a>
</div>

<div class="course-add2PL">
<a class="thickbox" href="http://www.google.com">Add Course <br />to Playlist</a>
</div>

<div class="course-add2Favorite noMargin">
<a class="thickbox" href="http://www.google.com">Add to <br />Favorite</a>
</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.course-downloadPF a,
.course-add2PL a,
.course-add2Favorite a,
.course-removeFavorite a {

    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#fff !important;
    line-height:1.1em;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:40px;
    background:url (sprite-courseDetails.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


.course-add2PL a {
    background:url (sprite-courseDetails.gif) -80px 0 no-repeat;
}
.course-add2Favorite a {
    background:url (sprite-courseDetails.gif) -160px 0 no-repeat;
}
.course-removeFavorite a {
    background:url (sprite-courseDetails.gif) -240px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

If anyone could take a look and give it a second opinion that would be appreciated as I'm sure its something small and silly that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Try adding overflow: auto; to the div.

Comment: just replace 'sprite-courseDetails.gif'

Comment: The above code works if i place it in different HTML file ( http://speedvid.tv/test/hover/index.html ) but with the main html document it doesn't work. Some other objects maybe interfering... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay in your css the style below does not have a closing brace

```
.whiteCLR {
    color: #fff; /* White */
```

There may be more errors but fix that one and then we'll see.

Wing

Comment: It worked !! closing the brace fixed the image problem & font problem in bonus. You are the man :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    .course-add2PL a {
        background: url('sprite-courseDetails.gif') -80px 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .course-add2Favorite a {
        background: url('sprite-courseDetails.gif') -160px 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .course-removeFavorite a {
        background: url('sprite-courseDetails.gif') -240px 0 no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove space between `url` and brackets `(...)`

This is not valid:

```
.class {
    background-image: url (image.png);
}
```

But this is:

```
.course-add2PL a {
    background: url(sprite-courseDetails.gif) -80px 0 no-repeat;
}
.course-add2Favorite a {
    background: url(sprite-courseDetails.gif) -160px 0 no-repeat;
}
.course-removeFavorite a {
    background: url(sprite-courseDetails.gif) -240px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Tried almost all tweaks with background attribute, still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Set the background image, not the background.... `background-image:url('sprite-courseDetails.gif');`

Comment: I tried all kind of attributes, it's not working... maybe someother object in that particular page is interrupting

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the background css per se.  You have parsing errors in your CSS file that fail to render all css beyond that error.  See line 214:

```
*letter-spacing: -0.01em; /* IE 7 and below */
```

Asterisk is incorrect.  There are several other parsing errors that need to be addressed.

You might want to check this file using a tool like http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator

Comment: I have fixed all parsing error. Still the same. Bad day for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm blind, I dont think that you have these styles defined in any css file that is connected to your page.  The only css file I can see is test.css and that does not contain these styles.

There are a few ways of defining the styles but the following should work

Create a file called 'whatever.css' and paste the above styles into it.

Then add the following inside your html head element

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="whatever.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That will link your page to the styles.

Sorry if I've misunderstood

Wing

Comment: Must be syntax error in your css then because Firebug is not picking up those styles - Firebug cant even so those styles in the css.